# Importing matplotlib gives error even though installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I was hoping someone could help me out.

System is MacOS Catalina.
Python 3.8
IDE: VS

I installed matplotlib using pip install matplotlib which I saw stuck in under python2.7. I uninstalled matplotlib and reinstalled it using pip3 install matplotlib and received the following message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/apple/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (46.0.0)
```

However, when I try to run my .py file with 'import matplotlib' it gives this error:

```
    import matplotlib as mpl 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I've tried searching different sources for the solution but I am now stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mostly running your python script with the command `python your_file.py`, try running as `python3 your_file.py` in your terminal. pip3 installs packages under python3, not the default python2.

This is because I believe your mac terminal uses python 2.x by default, therefore the command `python` uses python 2.x version and `python3` uses 3.x version that is available to execute the files. So if you want to install any packages under python 2.x you use `pip` as the command and to install packages under python 3.x you use `pip3` as the command

Comment: So this error is before I even run anything. There is a red squigly line under 'import' in my import statement. I don't think it would matter if I am running it python or python3 ___.py if the error is there to begin with

Comment: The red squiggly is because your text editor cannot identify matplotlib as an installed module. This may be due to your text editor using the default python 2.x version as its interpreter. That is not a problem actually if you can run the script, did you try `python3 your_file.py`? It should remove `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'` this error.

Comment: Yes, I tried running it as python3 ____.py and it says the same thing. I am using Visual Studio Code, and in the bottom left it says Python 3.8.1 64-bit

Comment: Oh ok...in that case try re-installing matplotlib with this command  `pip3 install matplotlib` and re-run your python script with `python3 your_file.py`. I had a similar issue with another package, doing this helped.

Comment: That install command just tells me the same error message as above, that all the requirements are already satisfied

Comment: Okay... I think you are not installing it under your user: Use `python3 -m pip3 install --user matplotlib` or  `python3 -m pip install --user matplotlib` to install matplotlib under your current user.

Comment: Hi, I tried to give it an upvote but it says that anyone who has under 15 reputation won't have their upvote publicly displayed, however it will still be recorded.